# How to remove a cookie

Tags: java, jquery, servlets, cookies, logout

I am trying to implement the logout functionality for my iPhone app, which uses jQuery mobile, JS at the client side and java at the server side. Currently what I have to do is to clear cookie and redirect to #loginpage tag in my index.html (I have only 1 HTML file in which there are multiple tags for the different pages). What I am doing as of now for the clearCookie is:

```
Cookie readCookie = null;
for (Cookie cookie : httpRequest.getCookies()) {
    if (cookie.getName().equals("CookieForLogin")) {
        readCookie = cookie;
        break;
    }
}

readCookie.setMaxAge(0);
httpResponse.addCookie(readCookie);
```

But this code is not clearing the cookie. I have tried the JS ways, i.e. to set the expiration date to some previous date, given on net but they didn't work too. Also I don't have a response method for `HttpServletResponse`. How do I clear the cookie that is set at the client side & also how to redirect to a particular tag?

Comment: You can try to use the juery.cookie ?

Comment: using $.cookie('CookieForLogin',null) didn't work.

Comment: Don't forget to `session.invalidate()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cookies are tied to a specific path. You need to make sure that you set the same path during cookie's removal as it was as during cookie's creation. It defaults to the currently requested folder in the URL (and would thus only be available in the same folder or all its subfolders). You'd better explicitly specify the path, otherwise it would be dependent on the currently requested folder in the URL. The cookie path information is like the maxage namely not available in the request cookie header.

Assuming that you created the cookie as follows,

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("CookieForLogin", cookieForLogin);
cookie.setPath("/somePath");
cookie.setMaxAge(maxAgeInSeconds);
// ...
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

it needs to be removed as follows:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("CookieForLogin", null);
cookie.setPath("/somePath");
cookie.setMaxAge(0);
// ...
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

The `/somePath` is just exemplary. You can also just use `/`, as long as it's the same in both cases.

Note, the same applies to the [Secure](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setSecure%28boolean%29) and [HTTP-only](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setHttpOnly%28boolean%29) flags of the cookie. If you  have initially set it to `true` during cookie's creation, then you should also set it to `true` during cookie's removal, they namely defaults to `false`.

That said, I'm not sure how it's useful to store the logged-in user as a cookie. You're basically also allowing the enduser to manipulate its value. Rather just store the logged-in user as a session attribute instead and call `session.invalidate()` on logout.

Comment: What I understood is just setting the maxage to 0 doesn't work.. We have to set the other parameters like the content, path, etc too.. Thanks @BalusC

Answer (score 1):

> `void setMaxAge(int expiry)`

we can remove cookie using method, known as `setMaxAge()`

```
Cookie c = new Coookie("x", "10");
```

if you set maxage as 0

```
c.setMaxAge(0); //it causes the cookie to be deleted.
```

if you set maxage as negative value

```
c.setMaxAge(-1);
// cookie is not stored persistently and will be deleted end of the browsing session.
```

Comment: This isn't practical though, setting just the max age won't remove the cookie in some cases. You'll have to set more attributes like path, etc.

Answer (score 0):

getMaxAge

public int getMaxAge()
Gets the maximum age in seconds of this Cookie.
By default, -1 is returned, which indicates that the cookie will persist until browser shutdown.

Returns:
an integer specifying the maximum age of the cookie in seconds; if negative, means the cookie persists until browser shutdown
See Also:
setMaxAge(int)

//Java API Documentation

IN short you need to set cookie age :

```
A negative value means that the cookie is not stored persistently and will be deleted when the Web browser exits. 
A zero value causes the cookie to be deleted.

 Cookie killMyCookie = new Cookie("mycookie", null);
 killMyCookie.setMaxAge(0);
 killMyCookie.setPath("/");
 response.addCookie(killMyCookie);
```